# Cannot write in file using loop in C

Tags: c, string-comparison, file-writing

I a trying to take file name as argument and write strings using loop until user enter "-1".

problem 1: writing is not happening in text file and always shows empty
problem 2: cannot compare input -1 and "-1" . Always runs the `else` statements.

Note: I also tried `fputs` but it did not work that time either.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "a");
//fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
char str[100];

printf("enter string\n");

bool flag = true;
while (flag == true) {
    //printf("\nEnter data to append: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    if (strcmp(str, "-1") == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
        printf("Text written in file: %s\n", str);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `fgets()` keeps the `<ENTER>`. Try `if (strcmp(str, "-1\n") == 0)` ... or remove the newline immediatly after checking that `fgets()` succeeded.

Comment: Side note: you must check if `fopen` succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing don't happen because of `strcmp`, I'm showing you my version of this with `atoi`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define buffer 128

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[buffer];
    int flag = 1;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w+");        //I prefer using write mode and not append
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");    //here you control if the file is opening correctly
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(flag)                             //you don't need to write while(flag==true) (that's not wrong)
    {
        printf("Insert string: ");          
        scanf("%s", str);

        if(atoi(str)==1)                    //the function strcmp as you wrote it will break after the 
            break;                          //first cicle, use atoi, it returns 1 if the string is a number 

        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", str);           //the \n is to get the next string on the next row 
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am learning c after java then python and it is giving me pain. So thanks again

Comment: @MerajHossenAkib if the answer is match for you, consider to `accept` it, this is not required , I just remind you in case of you don't know about the feature.

Comment: I'm new on StackOverflow so I don't know about this honestly, how I do it?

Comment: Given the OP's goal, you should write `if (atoi(str) == -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Because fget() reads new line character.

So once you do comparation, It looks like:

`strcmp("-1\n", "-1");`

or

`strcmp("-1\n\r", "-1");`

You will never break the loop.
To remove newline character, let try:

`strtok(str, "\n");`

or

`strtok(str, "\r\n");`

Comment: `strtok(str, "\n");` is not a reliable way to strip the newline: it will return `NULL` and leave `str` unchanged if `fgets()` read an empty line, ie: if `str` is `"\n"`. Use this instead: `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work with `strcmp` your if statement should be `if(strcmp(str, "-1\n"))` because fgets reads also the \n character.